# Javascript -> webcam -> SVG

Tags: javascript, webcam

Is there anyway to use the input from my laptop's cam using either
https://github.com/taboca/CamCanvas-API-
or the jquery webcam plugin
and then use the actual webcam image to produce an SVG image?
I'm doing an art show in a few weeks and want the camera to be the source
for some SVG animations, so that the audience has some form of interaction
with the piece. I know that both CamCanvas Jquery Webcam output in SWF i.e. flash
but can the flash file displaying the webcam be accessed from javascript and then used in
a graphic library like raphael or would I have to write everything in flash?

Is it possible to use the html 5 video tag and access the webcam on my laptop?

Further, could I just stream my camera using VLC in OGG and then the OGG stream as the input for my SVG animation?

Answer (score 3):

SVG is used for vector graphics. So "webcam" and "SVG" don't fit together very well.

I don't think `<video>` can access devices - so you probably go better with Flash.

Comment: I understand the difference, but even a JPEG had a color table or some info about the image inside that could be used to generate an SVG image. Does the flash file that the jquery webcam plugin produces have a readable image format? I saw on the CamCanvas site that someone is working on edge detection.

Comment: sorry about the mess CamCanvas can render the webcam to a canvas which is manipulatable, so that's a start.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use the `<video>` tag to access a webcam – right now.

In the future (long-term), you'll be able to use the [`<device>` tag](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/commands.html#devices), but no browser supports it yet.

However, you might be able to [hack together a stream to a `<video>` tag using VLC](http://nicklothian.com/blog/2009/11/17/using-a-webcam-with-html-5-via-vlc/), since it sounds like this is something you'll be running only on a machine you control.  (Also take a look at this guy's [second post on taking an image from video and manipulating it on a `<canvas>`](http://nicklothian.com/blog/2009/11/18/augmented-reality-virtual-keyboard-using-html-5-video/).  There's a [demo](http://demo.nicklothian.com/keypad/) that just blew my mind.)

Comment: that's amazing (and interestingly I was looking at this site earlier today). Yeah, that is similar to what I'm looking at. It does appear that the video -> canvas -> manipulation works. I just git'd camcanvas and will start work with it tomorrow.